# How to do a manage.py command from within a file

Tags: python, django

How would I do the following in a python file:

```
# django project is imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    python manage.py es_sync_index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('es_sync_index')
```

Comment: How would I do the following command with arguments? `python manage.py filterindex -n credits` ?